# An [elementary] rename?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag [elementary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elementary) is supposed to be used for [elementary OS](https://elementary.io/), but it is often used for basic questions (not to be confused with [BASIC questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/basic)). Consider, for example, this [generic C question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71843363/revisions) that I first discovered the tag on.

Searching for [questions that don't contain "elementary OS"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Belementary%5D+-%22elementary+OS%22+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) gives a list of questions that may need to be retagged. (I am struggling somewhat with this as I am not familiar at all with eOS.)

Can we retag the questions that need to be, then rename the tag [elementary-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os)? Note: the official name is stylized like that, with a space before "OS". Also, not all questions in the tag are on-topic, so close as you will.

The [Vala tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vala/info) should be edited to reflect any tag renaming.

---

Honorable mention: [elementary-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elementary-functions) (about the [concept in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20elementary%20function,e.g.%2C%20arcsin%2C%20log%2C%20or)) should probably also be retagged, into the specific tags that each question is asking about, such as [trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry). (One question was tagged with both [elementary*] tags.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've renamed the tag and updated the Vala tag wiki.  Someone should feel free to fix the tagging of the questions in the tag.